# Where is the SDE.SDEXMLTOTEXT() function located?

Tags: sql, enterprise-geodatabase, oracle-dbms, function, geodatabase-xml

*Oracle 18c 10.7.1 EGDB:*

In SDE.GDB_ITEMS_VW, there is a function being used called `SDE.SDEXMLTOTEXT()`:

```
sde.sdexmltotext(d1.xml_doc) AS definition,
sde.sdexmltotext(d2.xml_doc) AS documentation,
sde.sdexmltotext(d3.xml_doc) AS iteminfo,
```

I want to look at the PL/SQL definition of that `SDE.SDEXMLTOTEXT()` function. I'm curious if the  function uses up-to-date Oracle XML functionality, or if it uses deprecated/slower XML functionality.

Related: [Update Oracle GDB docs: EXTRACTVALUE is deprecated, use XMLTABLE instead (faster)](https://community.esri.com/t5/data-management-ideas/update-oracle-gdb-docs-extractvalue-is-deprecated/idi-p/1187342)

---

I've tried looking for the `SDE.SDEXMLTOTEXT()` function in the SDE owner in my GDB. But I cant seem to find it in the functions or packages folders in the database.

Question:

Where is the `SDE.SDEXMLTOTEXT()` function located? Is its definition stored in the SDE schema? Or in the EXTPROC.DLL? etc.

Answer (score 2):

In oracle, SDE.SDEXMLText is a user-defined operator.

select dbms_metadata.get_ddl('OPERATOR', 'SDEXMLTOTEXT')
from dual;

returns:

CREATE OR REPLACE OPERATOR "SDE"."SDEXMLTOTEXT" BINDING
(BLOB) RETURN CLOB
USING "SDE"."ST_GEOM_UTIL"."SDEXML_TO_TEXT_F"